# Need Schema Microdata example of how to list 'required documention' of a organization or business?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, microdata

Hello and thank you for the opportunity to post a question. I have searched the Internet, Schema.org and Stackoverflow for an answer to my question. Maybe I am not asking my question correctly... I have a directory website that lists various organizations and businesses. Almost all the Organizations are Government funded and require documentation from a client in order to receive services.

- For example: 'Name of Food Bank, Address, Telephone, Description, Documentation required: Photo ID, Birth Certificate, Utility Bill, EBT card.' The same would be for a Hospital, Substance Use Program, Medical, Dental, etc.

I cannot find any schema for how to list the documentation that the organization requires from a client in order to be eligible for services. I'm sure it's got to be somewhere!

Most likely, there is a way, but for just one specific entity type. I need a way to use for any entity type.

My question is how would I use Microdata to list the (any) organizations/business 'Required Documentation' of a client?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such an option. You might start from what's it about.

From what you're saying, some companies offer some services. So we could use [Service](https://schema.org/Service) and [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) entities.
Customers need to provide documentation, which means it's an application, so we can use [ApplyAction](https://schema.org/ApplyAction) as the top/main entity, because that seems to be the point.

As for "required documentation", can't think of anything other than just list it in the description, as is.

Here's how it might look (`ApplyAction` that has a `Service` as an `object`, offered by one of the companies, with requirements listed in the `description`):

```
<div>
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/ApplyAction" itemscope>
    <div itemprop="object" itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="serviceType" content="Hospital, Substance Use Program, Medical, Dental, etc." />
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Documentation required: Photo ID, Birth Certificate, Utility Bill, EBT card" />
      <div itemprop="provider" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="One of various organizations and businesses" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```